# show/hide fieldgroup with ajax drupal 7

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a field group that contain sub field group with almost 30 fields
also I have a `checkbox` field that I want ajaxly show hide field group accoridng   checking event of it.

I have no problem with ajaxly show hide a field according to checking.but I have no idea how I can perform with  fieldgroup.
Any idea?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the form elements to be unloaded by default, and then loaded in via ajax if required.

Comment: maybe in edit of node should be loaded and in uncheck hide them(remove)

Comment: According to the [FAPI docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) fieldsets can't have `#ajax` set on them so my guess is you'll need to do this manully

Comment: @Clive hi Clive,Thanks for your attention. I know I have to do it in  form_alter, but I have some idea how can I perform it,maybe get groups in form $from['#groups'] and foreach of them disable sub fields or some thing like this. you have better idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you take a look at [conditionals fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields), works great for node-form and can help you to build your own code.

Oskar

Comment: I dont want use it, I want programmically done ,although conditionals fields is powerful module but if heavy module not suitable for my small requires.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a programatic replacement for conditional fields, then you are looking for the #states attribute in the form api.  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states
Add that in a form_alter and it does the ajax for you.